# Pandas format column as currency

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'A':['A','B','C','D'],
         'C':[12355.00,12555.67,640.00,7000]
        })
df

    A   C
0   A   12355.00
1   B   12555.67
2   C   640.00
3   D   7000.00
```

I'd like to convert the values to dollars in thousands of USD like this:

```
    A   C
0   A   $12.3K
1   B   $12.5K
2   C    $0.6K
3   D    $7.0K
```

The second thing I need to do is somehow get these into a Seaborn heat map, which only accepts floats and integers. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35003011/seaborn-heatmap-currency-format) for more on the heat map aspect.

I'm assuming once the floats are converted to currency, they will be in object format but I'm hoping there's a way around that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
    def format(x):
        return "${:.1f}K".format(x/1000)


    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'A':['A','B','C','D'],
         'C':[12355.00,12555.67,640.00,7000]
        })

    df['C'] = df['C'].apply(format)

    print(df)
```

Comment: Alternatively you could use `locale.currency(value, grouping=True)` but you will need to import and set the local: `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')`

Comment: Good one here -- a friendly note, `format` is a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) of python, which python lets you overwrite, but it is usually a very bad idea.  it would be better to name it something like `to_usd`, not only because it is more concise, but because if you overwrite these built-in functions, it risks undesirable, mysterious bugs to happen, especially if it becomes part of a larger codebase.

Answer (score 22):

Or you could use a lambda function for shorter syntax

```
df['C'] = df['C'].apply(lambda x: "${:.1f}k".format((x/1000)))
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This answer would be enhanced by some explanation. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 7):

Or you could use a [lambda function](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) and [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) for even *shorter* shorter syntax

```
df['C'] = df['C'].map(lambda x: f"${x/1000:.1f}k")
```

Comment: For multiple columns you'll need to pass as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68068042/typeerror-unsupported-format-string-passed-to-series-format). `df[["A", "B", "C"]] = df[["A", "B", "C"]].apply(lambda series: series.apply(lambda value: f"{value:,}")
)`

Answer (score 3):

#### `Flexibile formatting using Babel`

If you are looking for a flexible way of formatting currency's and numbers for different locale's, I suggest using [Babel](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/):

Example data

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'A':['A','B','C','D'],
         'C':[12355.00,12555.67,640.00,7000]
        })
print(df)

   A         C
0  A  12355.00
1  B  12555.67
2  C    640.00
3  D   7000.00
```

Formatting dollar currency:

```py
from babel.numbers import format_currency

df["C"] = df["C"].apply(lambda x: format_currency(x, currency="USD", locale="en_US"))

   A           C
0  A  $12,355.00
1  B  $12,555.67
2  C     $640.00
3  D   $7,000.00
```

Formatting euro currency (notice the difference in thousands and decimal seperator):

```py
df["C"] = df["C"].apply(lambda x: format_currency(x, currency="EUR", locale="nl_NL"))

   A            C
0  A  € 12.355,00
1  B  € 12.555,67
2  C     € 640,00
3  D   € 7.000,00
```

Comment: Broadly Babel is useful, but the question was at least in part about representing amounts in thousands of dollars (ie. dividing by 1000, and grouping by a known unit for thousands, like 'k').  As far as I can tell, Babel doesn't support dividing into thousands nor localising 'thousands' as it does for other kinds of applied units (like it can with the format_units() function, or as you demonstrate for currencies).  It is a shame, as being able to translate 'thousands' (eg 'k') for different non-English contexts would be useful.  If you know how to do this, I'd love to know how too!

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use the [format](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.5/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html) method of pandas' *Styler* object (returned by the pandas.io.formats.style.Styler).

```
(df
 .assign(C=df.C / 1000)
 .style.format({"C": "$ {:.1f} k"})
)


    A   C
0   A   $ 12.4 k
1   B   $ 12.6 k
2   C   $ 0.6 k
3   D   $ 7.0 k
```