# How to format numbers floats with comma and dot

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data that I need to format:

```
  Ativo        high       close
 HTMX11       169.8       169.8
 KNHY11       116.0       116.0
 FAED11       272.3       272.3
 FLRP11     1579.92     1579.92
 FVPQ11       215.5       215.5
```

Need to convert 1579.92 to 1.579,92

not a problem, since I can do with:

```
import pandas as pd
import locale
locale.setlocale (locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_br.utf-8')
pd.set_option ('display.float_format', lambda x: locale.format ('%. 2f', x, grouping = True))
```

but when I need to convert the column to a string and add some letters, numbers are kept only with commas:

I need complete formatting.

```
df['close'] = '$' + df['close'].astype()
df['close']
```

Results in:

```
Fechamento
  R$ 169,8
  R$ 116,0
  R$ 272,3
R$ 1579,92
  R$ 215,5
```

desired output:

```
R$ 1.579,92
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print number with commas as thousands separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823058/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators)

Comment: how about https://stackoverflow.com/a/43001878/1335793

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed, the `display` option only affects the display. So you need to do an explicit conversion, possibly using `locale.format()`, if you want to actually convert the column to a string.

The `locale` methods are also somewhat limited in what they can do, so I'd recommend using the [Babel](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/) module for internationalization and localization. Babel has a richer API and it actually ships localization data you can use (so you don't need to depend on it being available in your O.S.) It also includes data about currencies, so it can do that conversion for you as well.

You can install Babel with:

```
pip install Babel
```

And then you can convert your columns to use Brazilian Real currency with:

```
from babel.numbers import format_currency

df['close'] = df['close'].apply(
    lambda v: format_currency(v, 'BRL', locale='pt_BR'),
)
```

Or, to convert both "high" and "close" together:

```
df[['high', 'close']] = df[['high', 'close']].applymap(
    lambda v: format_currency(v, 'BRL', locale='pt_BR'),
)
```

If you're generating HTML from the DataFrame (for example, in a Jupyter notebook), you can use the [Styling API](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html) to apply the format only when rendering the DataFrame, keeping the underlying data as floats and not strings:

```
df.style.format(
    lambda v: format_currency(v, 'BRL', locale='pt_BR'),
    subset=['high', 'close'],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from babel.numbers import format_currency
df = pd.DataFrame({"close":[169.8,116.0,272.3,1579.92,215.5]})
df['close'].apply(lambda x :format_currency(x,'BRL', locale='pt_BR'))
```

output:

```
0      R$ 169,80
1      R$ 116,00
2      R$ 272,30
3    R$ 1.579,92
4      R$ 215,50
```