# TypeError: unsupported format string passed to Series.__format__

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to add a thousand separator to my dash cards and all my efforts have been futile. This solution is found to be more accurate but it gives me an error

TypeError: unsupported format string passed to Series.**format**

```
@app.callback(
[Output('sls', 'children'),
Output('wngs', 'children'),
Output('rvne', 'children')],
Input('year', 'value')
)

def card_update(select_year):
dff=df_good.copy()
df_formattedd=dff.groupby(['year'], as_index=False)[['Net Sale', 'Winnings','Revenue']].sum()
df_formattedd[['Net Sale','Winnings','Revenue']]=df_formattedd[['Net Sale','Winnings','Revenue']].apply(lambda x:round(x,2))
df_formattedd[['Net Sale','Winnings','Revenue']]= df_formattedd[['Net Sale','Winnings','Revenue']].apply(lambda x: f'{x:,}')
sales=df_formattedd[df_formattedd['year']==select_year]['Net Sale']
winnings=df_formattedd[df_formattedd['year']==select_year]['Winnings']
revenue=df_formattedd[df_formattedd['year']==select_year]['Revenue']

return sales, winnings, revenue
```

Answer (score 10):

Short abstracted example code that reproduces your problem:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": [1000000.111, 1000000.222, 1000000.333],
        "B": [2000000.111, 2000000.222, 2000000.333],
        "C": [3000000.111, 3000000.222, 3000000.333],
    }
)

df[["A", "B", "C"]] = df[["A", "B", "C"]].apply(lambda x: round(x, 2))
df[["A", "B", "C"]] = df[["A", "B", "C"]].apply(lambda x: f'{x:,}')
```

gives:

> TypeError: unsupported format string passed to Series.**format**

The problem is with the last line where you try to format the numbers.

The problem is that `x` in the lambda function refers to a Pandas Series and not a number. A Series doesn't support the type of formatting string you're using:

> The ',' option signals the use of a comma for a thousands separator.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html

---

Instead you could do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": [1000000.111, 1000000.222, 1000000.333],
        "B": [2000000.111, 2000000.222, 2000000.333],
        "C": [3000000.111, 3000000.222, 3000000.333],
    }
)

df[["A", "B", "C"]] = df[["A", "B", "C"]].apply(lambda x: round(x, 2))
df[["A", "B", "C"]] = df[["A", "B", "C"]].apply(
    lambda series: series.apply(lambda value: f"{value:,}")
)
```

So the idea behind the nested `apply` here is: For each column in the DataFrame `df[["A", "B", "C"]]` take each row value and apply the string formatter to it. The row values are just floats so the string formatter is able to handle that.

Result

```
>>> print(df)
              A             B             C
0  1,000,000.11  2,000,000.11  3,000,000.11
1  1,000,000.22  2,000,000.22  3,000,000.22
2  1,000,000.33  2,000,000.33  3,000,000.33
```

Alternatively you can set the format using [`pd.options.display.float_format`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html):

```
pd.options.display.float_format = "{:,}".format
```

Keep in mind that this is applies to more than just `df[["A", "B", "C"]]`.

Comment: Saved my life :) with this, thank you Bas, but can you explain why you have to do what you did?

Comment: @mikelowry I've added some more info. Hopefully that is more clear.

Comment: Thank you for elucidating!! Greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Another approach here would be to use .applymap()

For readability, we can create a function to format the numbers, and then use the function in the .applymap().

```
def format_ints(row):
    return f"{row:,}"

df[["A", "B", "C"]] = df[["A", "B", "C"]].applymap(format_ints)
```

[Documentation reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)