# Apply a function to multiple columns, giving error : unsupported format string passed to Series.__format__

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns

I have dataframe:

```
    Name     in    hit    out
0    Tom  49694  50308  52673
1   nick    305    658    658
2  krish  50308  56356  62015
```

it has data in seconds, now i want to convert it into hh:mm:ss ,but with hh going beyond 24 hours and
the desired output df :

```
    Name        in       hit       out
0    Tom  13:48:14  13:58:28  14:37:53
1   nick   0:05:05   0:10:58   0:10:58
2  krish  13:58:28  15:39:16  17:13:35
```

So i defined a function:

```
def to_hms(s):
    m, s = divmod(s, 60)
    h, m = divmod(m, 60)
    return '{}:{:0>2}:{:0>2}'.format(h, m, s)
```

And then tried to apply the functions to all as

```
cols = ['in','hit','out']

df[cols] = df[cols].apply(to_hms, axis=1)
```

But as the title says, iam getting the error :

```
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to Series.__format__
```

If i try to apply it 1 column at a time it works, but the df has like 10 columns to be converted.

Any workaround to get the desired output.
TIA.

Comment: I guess a quick workaround would be to write a for loop `for col in cols: df[col] = df[col].apply`.

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68068042/typeerror-unsupported-format-string-passed-to-series-format).

Comment: @JonasPalačionis, it worked like a charm, i completely forgot about using  for loop for the task