# How to convert float to currency(US dollar) in a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, currency-formatting

[image: my data frame looks like this]

How to convert decimal value to US dollar in pandas?

For instance 8.301400 should be $8,30,1400

Comment: you can use df.apply on the specific column of the dataframe as explained: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35019156/pandas-format-column-as-currency

Comment: is it sufficient to multiply by `100000`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['column'] = df['column'].apply(lambda x: f"${x*100000:,.2f}")
```

I think 100000 is the multiplier, but if it's another one just change it above.