# How to sort dataframe result based on column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/new/"
page = requests.get(url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}, timeout=1)
pagedata = page.text
usecols = ["Name", "Price", "1h", "24h", "MarketCap", "Volume"]#, "Blockchain"]

df = pd.read_html(pagedata)[0] #Checking table
df[["Name", "Symbol"]] = df["Name"].str.split(r"\d+", expand=True)
df = df.rename(columns={"Fully Diluted Market Cap": "MarketCap"})[usecols]
dfAsString = df.to_string(index=False)

print(dfAsString)
```

Current Code Output: (Truncated)

```
               Name            Price      1h      24h       MarketCap       Volume
0        DollarPepe         $0.02752  22.64%  336.25%              $3     $456,913
1       Billy Token      $0.00002822  41.69%   75.80%      $1,958,942   $6,999,241
2              JEFF          $0.1946   4.42%  226.18%     $19,458,328  $19,744,583
3            PUG AI   $0.00000001459  10.80%   15.84%      $1,459,428     $239,454
4         FART COIN    $0.0000004281   1.13%   42.13%     $42,806,075      $46,604
[30 rows x 6 columns]
```

How to produce the outpur sorted based on a particular column (24h)? -> Truncated

```
               Name            Price      1h      24h       MarketCap       Volume
0        DollarPepe         $0.02752  22.64%  336.25%              $3     $456,913
2              JEFF          $0.1946   4.42%  226.18%     $19,458,328  $19,744,583
1       Billy Token      $0.00002822  41.69%   75.80%      $1,958,942   $6,999,241
4         FART COIN    $0.0000004281   1.13%   42.13%     $42,806,075      $46,604
3            PUG AI   $0.00000001459  10.80%   15.84%      $1,459,428     $239,454
[30 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would convert all the numeric columns in your df to numeric values; then you can sort them easily (you can always add back `$` and `%` as required on display).

```py
numcols = df.columns[df.columns != 'Name']
df[numcols] = df[numcols].apply(lambda c:pd.to_numeric(c.str.replace(r'[^\d.]|(?<!\d)\.|\.(?!\d)', '', regex=True)))
df = df.sort_values('24h', ascending=False)
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
          Name         Price     1h     24h  MarketCap    Volume
0   DollarPepe  2.752000e-02  22.64  336.25          3    456913
2         JEFF  1.946000e-01   4.42  226.18   19458328  19744583
1  Billy Token  2.822000e-05  41.69   75.80    1958942   6999241
4    FART COIN  4.281000e-07   1.13   42.13   42806075     46604
3       PUG AI  1.459000e-08  10.80   15.84    1459428    239454
```

Note the non-numeric character replacement is more complicated than just `[^\d.]` as would be implied by your sample data; this is because some of the other price values fetched from that page have `...` in them (presumably because they are too small to represent). Ideally you need to figure out how to get those as exact values; otherwise they can only be approximated.

Alternatively, you can sort on the values by converting them to floats before passing the series to `sort_values`:

```
df = df.sort_values('24h', ascending=False, key=lambda v:v.str.replace('%', '').astype(float))
```

Output:

```
          Name           Price      1h      24h    MarketCap       Volume
0   DollarPepe        $0.02752  22.64%  336.25%           $3     $456,913
2         JEFF         $0.1946   4.42%  226.18%  $19,458,328  $19,744,583
1  Billy Token     $0.00002822  41.69%   75.80%   $1,958,942   $6,999,241
4    FART COIN   $0.0000004281   1.13%   42.13%  $42,806,075      $46,604
3       PUG AI  $0.00000001459  10.80%   15.84%   $1,459,428     $239,454
```

Comment: At which part of the code it will be inserted?

Comment: @DrewDuazeh after `df = df.rename(columns={"Fully Diluted Market Cap": "MarketCap"})[usecols]`

Comment: Getting error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sortvalues'

Comment: @DrewDuazeh there should be an `_` in `sort_values`. Sorry, cut and paste problem by me.

Comment: The result in the MarketCap 1.17092e+07. Is there a way to show all the values like $11,709,185

Comment: @DrewDuazeh you could use an approach as in the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35019156/pandas-format-column-as-currency

Comment: I just notice now that if Im using this line, `usecols = ["Name", "Price", "1h", "24h", "MarketCap", "Volume", "Blockchain"]`, the last column display NaN. Why is that?

Comment: @DrewDuazeh it's because it's a non-numeric column. You need to make sure it's not in `numcols`: `numcols = df.columns[~df.columns.isin(['Name', 'Blockchain'])]`